# How can i apply various rules in recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have list of `Rules` and each rules in in different class

```
rules = ['RuleA', 'RuleB', 'RuleC']
```

where RuleA .. are clasess

Each RuleA is like

```
class RuleA(object):
       def __init__(self, entry):
           self.entry = entry

       def apply():
          return {data:[l1,l2], final: true}
```

I want to apply like

```
  ces = []
  for entry in entries:    
    for rule in rules:
        r= rule(entry)
        res = r.apply()

        if res['final']:
           for e in res['data']:
               ces.append(e)
               # stop processing this entry
        else: 
           go further
```

Basically `if res['final'] is True` then it means no further processing required and then append the list items to `ces`

but if `res['final'] is flase` then i want that `entry` to go through further Rules unless

```
res['final'] is True
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could achieve what you want with a `break` statement (`break` simply terminates the `for` loop and continues execution after the loop). Your code could look like this, then:

```
if res['final']:
   for e in res['data']:
       ces.append(e)
       break
```

There would be no need for an `else` statement because the loop would continue looping by default if it is not stopped.

Comment: Actually i also want that if final is false then `ces` should also go through further Rules as well as entries